# When is $r = r^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{l}\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

When is $r = r^{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{l}\mathbb{Z}$, where p is a prime number and l is a natural number? It obviously is the case for [0] and [1], but I am having difficulties proving that it's not possible for other r.

Comment: Hint: $r^2 = r$ is equivalent to $r(r-1) = 0$. What are the zero-divisors mod a prime power?

Comment: I'm not sure I see why those are equivalent.

Comment: Just move the $r$ on the right side to the left and factor.

Comment: I don't see how I would move the r to the other side apart from multiplying with $r^{-1}$ on both sides, and I don't know if r is an unit.

Comment: Move it to the other side by subtracting it (hence why you get $0$ left on the right).

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. But I don't have any theorems about the zero-divisors mod a prime power, except that I know that a a quotient ring mod a composite number is not a domain, meaning that at least one zero-divisor exists.

Comment: Finding these zero-divisors is a nice exercise, which is not particularly tricky.

Answer (score 3):

In the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z} \pmod {p^\ell}$, which elements $x$ satisfy the condition $x=x^2$.  We want to solve $x \equiv x^2$, or $x(x-1) \equiv 0, \pmod {p^\ell}$. Thus $x(x-1)$ must be a multiple of $p^\ell$.  But $p$ is a prime, and it is not possible for both $x$ and $x-1$ to be multiples of $p$ unless one of them is 0.